# XmlPullParserException while attempting to parse XML as a String

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing, inputstream

An API returns a String response containing something like the following:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>                                                                             
<!DOCTYPE response>                                                                              
<response version='1.0'>                                                    
    <errorcode>0</errorcode>                                                                                    
    <result>
        <value>123</value>
    </result>                                                                         
</response>
```

This response is turned into an `InputStream`, and passed to a `parseXml()` method:

```
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(response.body().string().getBytes());
parseXml(stream);
```

Below is the body of the `parseXml()` method:

```
public Map parseXml(InputStream in) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {

    try {
        XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
        parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
        parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_DOCDECL, false);
        parser.setInput(in, null);
        parser.nextTag();
        return readResponse(parser);
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
}
```

When this code is executed, the following error is produced and points to the line containing `parser.nextTag()`:

> org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:END_DOCUMENT null@1:1 in java.io.InputStreamReader)

What is going on here? I had a suspicion that the `<!DOCTYPE>` line in the XML may have been throwing the parser off, but setting `parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_DOCDECL, false);` does not seem to resolve the issue. What is the cause of this error, and how can it be fixed?

**Below are changes suggested in the comments:**

Replace `ByteArrayInputStream` with `StringReader`

```
StringReader reader = new StringReader(response.body().string());
parseXml(reader);
```

then

```
public Map parseXml(StringReader in) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {

    try {
        XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
        parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
        parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_DOCDECL, false);
        parser.setInput(in);
        parser.nextTag();
        return readResponse(parser);
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
}
```

these changes produce a similar error:

> org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:END_DOCUMENT null@1:1 in java.io.StringReader)

Comment: Try using a `StringReader` instead of a `ByteArrayInputStream`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I replaced the `InputStream` with `StringReader reader = new StringReader(response.body().string());` and then passed that `Reader` to `parseXml()`. Inside `parseXml()` the reader is then passed to `parser.setInput()`. With these changes the same `XmlPullParserException` occurs (though with `StringReader` replacing `InputStreamReader`) in the error.